# posting json data to mongodb using angular controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, mongodb

I'm atempting to feed json data from html via angular controller to mongodb. But the data mongodb shows is completely different from what's expected.What is expected is showing up in the mongodb console the data entered into the textarea exactly as shown.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"service type text","type":"password","value":""}]
```

Here's my html

```
<div ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
<div ng-controller="sendJsonController" class="ng-scope">
<textarea id="inputFields" rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="input"></textarea><br> 
<input ng-click="senddata" type="button" value="submit"><br>
 </div>  
</div>
```

---- angularjs controller---

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('sendJsonController',
    function senddata($http, $scope) {
        var string = $scope.input;
        console.log($scope.input);
        var json=angular.toJson(string);

        $http.post('fields/addFields', json).success(function (msg) {
            $scope.status = msg;
        });
    });


 But what's shown in mongodb console is:
 [{"_id":"55d9df5fd7ee17b83142829a"}]
```

expected:

```
 [{"id":"1","name":"service type text","type":"password","value":""}]
```

Comment: No need to stringify the data, `$http` does that for you. But you do need to create an object so you are sending a `key/value` pair and not just a value

Comment: @charlietfl I'm kind of new to angular, it'd highly appreciated if you could show up with an example, or at least a link

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">
 <div ng-controller="sendJsonController" class="ng-scope">
  <input type="text" id="inputField1" ng-model="input.name">
  <input type="text" id="inputField2" ng-model="input.type">
  <br> 
  <input ng-click="senddata(input)" type="button" value="submit"><br>
 </div>  
</div>
```

In your controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('sendJsonController', ['$http', '$scope',
function($http, $scope) {
    $scope.senddata = function (input) {
      $http.post('fields/addFields', {name: input.name,
        type: input.type}).success(function (msg) {
          $scope.status = msg;
        });
    }
}]);
```

What you are doing is passing all the data you need in one textarea box, but you aren't sending a JSON object. `{}` , but if you wanted to separate the text in the textarea box for example `row1 - name, row2 -type`, you will have to perform another logic that separates them and then you would pass it into an object, `separately`.`{"row1": "name", "row2": "type"}`

Comment: What this gives when [{"id":"3","name":"service type text","type":"password","value":""}] is fed into textarea in mongo console is {"_id":"55daafcf6d6097c01123d88f","data":"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"service type text\",\"type\":\"password\",\"value\":\"\"}]"}

Comment: Instead how do I get the data on the mongo console  to appear in this format [{"id":"1","name":"service type text","type":"password","value":""}] ?